Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal - Microsoft Project
I'm trying to publish a file in PWA (Project Web App) but when I try to save the file I get the following error:
ActiveCacheQueuedMessageExecutionError:
ActiveCacheQueuedMessageExecutionError (12005). Detalhes: id='12005' name='ActiveCacheQueuedMessageExecutionError' uid='9c3411fb-afa1-ef11-bd96-00155d88b404' error='System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal. at System.Decimal..ctor(Double value) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.WinProjUtility.P12Deserializer.ReadPropertyValue(CustomFieldMetadata cfmd, Int32 endOffset, Int32 valSize, CustomFieldValues cfValues, P12ContainerHeader cntrHeader) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.WinProjUtility.P12Deserializer.ReadCustomNonNullProps(P12ContainerHeader cntrHeader, Int32 rowEndOffset, CustomFieldValues cfValues, Dictionary`2 graphicalIndicators) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.WinProjUtility.P12Deserializer.ReadNextCustomFieldValuesRow(P12ContainerHeader cntrHeader, Int32 cntrDataEndOffset, CustomFieldValues cfValues) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.WinProjUtility.P12Deserializer.ProcessCustomFieldValuesContainerData(P12ContainerHeader cntrHeader, CustomFieldValues cfValues) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.WinProjUtility.CustomFieldValues.ProcessCustomFieldValues(Guid projGuid, String projName, DataStoreEnum store, Guid jobGuid, DateTime modDate, Int32 revRank, Int32 modRevCounter, Byte[] cntrBytes, ProjectType projectType, Guid sessionGuid, Guid checkOutByResUid, String sessionDescription, Boolean isNewProject, Guid projectOwnerGuid, Int16 dataFormatVersion, String winprojBuildNumber) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.WinProjUtility.WinProjSynchronousSaveProcessor.ProcessCustomFieldValuesContainer(Guid projGuid, String projName, DataStoreEnum store, Guid userGuid, Guid sessionGuid, String sessionDescription, Guid jobGuid, ProjectType projType, DateTime modDate, Int32 revRank, Int32 modRevCounter, Boolean isOverwriteSave, Boolean isNewProject, Guid projectOwnerGuid, Byte[] cntrBytes, Int16 dataFormatVersion, String winprojBuildNumber) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.WinProjUtility.P12Deserializer.ProcessCustomFieldValuesContainer(P12ContainerHeader cntrHeader) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.WinProj.SaveProjectData(SerializableProjectSaveData serializableProjectSaveData, WinProjTraceContext traceContext, Boolean projNeedsTaskListSync) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.Queue.ProcessACMessage.DispatchSaveProjectChunkMessage(Message msg, MessageContext mContext) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.Queue.ProcessACMessage.HandleMessage(Message msg, Group messageGroup, JobTicket jobTicket, MessageContext mContext)'
In our files we have many custom fields with formulas, which probably generated this error in some formula calculation, but we are having a lot of trouble finding it.
Is it possible to know in which specific field the error occurs, some identifier, ...?
Thanks for any help in advance.
Project Error
